Reading netcdf in R with lon lat dimensions reported as single 1D vector
I need to work with these data in R: https://zenodo.org/records/1209296 in particular "irrigation water use v2.7z". I opened the netcdf inside R both with terra and raster library. I should have a lon lat grid over the world with 480 layers (months). But the format when I open them is the following.
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 480, 64028, 30733440  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.007481219, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0.9962594, 480.0037, 0.5, 480.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : withd_irr_h08.nc 
names      : withd_irr 
zvar       : withd_irr 

How can I move to a raster with two dimension (lat, lon) and 480 layers? The resolution is 0.5°.

archive::archive_extract('~/Downloads/irrigation water use v2.7z') unzips to working directory, 8 files, 2GB...[1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named grid_num BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point", you did get this warning with <- terra::rast('withd_irr_h08.nc')? same (no dimvar) for grid_num seen with nc_in <- ncdf4::nc_open('withd_irr_h08.nc'); print(nc_in). terra won't heal a somewhat malformed .nc, (same no dim_var in all files) the adventure is then in ncdf4 first. As far as I've taken it...

Your data is completely non-standard and not self-descriptive. In other words, no library will give you a one-stop solution.
With package ncdfCF I see the following file structure:
> library(ncdfCF)

> irr <- open_ncdf("~/withd_irr_h08.nc")
> irr
<Dataset> withd_irr_h08 
Resource   : withd_irr_h08.nc 
Format     : classic 
Conventions: (not indicated) 
Keep open  : FALSE 

Variables:
 name      units    data_type axes           
 withd_irr mm/month NC_DOUBLE grid_num, month
 lon       degree   NC_DOUBLE grid_num       
 lat       degree   NC_DOUBLE grid_num       

Axes:
 id axis name     length values                      unit               
 1  T    month      480  [1971-02-01 ... 2011-01-01] months since 1971-1
 0       grid_num 64028  [1 ... 64028]

The data variable withd_irr does not use a longitude-latitude grid, instead it has an axis grid_num which holds 64,028 locations, same as the lon and lat variables (which you want to be axes if terra should recognise them, but they are not).
The solution to your problem is to extract the data for the 3 variables, put them in a data.frame, then convert that to a terra::SpatRaster. You will have to do the conversion for each month individually because the various steps are available for matrices but not for arrays:
# Read entire data arrays
> lon <- irr[["lon"]][]
> lat <- irr[["lat"]][]
> withd <- irr[["withd_irr"]][]

# Make a data.frame with lon, lat and all 480 months of withd_irr
> df <- data.frame(lon, lat, withd, check.names = FALSE)

# Convert a month of data to a SpatRaster
> r <- rast(df[c("lon", "lat", "1971-02-01")])
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 279, 720, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -56, 83.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source(s)   : memory
name        : 1971-02-01 
min value   :    0.00000 
max value   :   96.28087

All months in one go
Putting it all together and making a single SpatRaster:
> library(ncdfCF)

> irr <- open_ncdf("~/withd_irr_h08.nc")
> lon <- irr[["lon"]][]
> lat <- irr[["lat"]][]
> withd <- irr[["withd_irr"]][]
> df <- data.frame(lon, lat, withd, check.names = FALSE)
> mon_str <- names(df)[-(1:2)] # drop lon, lat

# Build the SpatRaster structure from the first month
> r <- rast(df[c("lon", "lat", mon_str[1])])

# Now add the remaining months
> for (i in 2:length(mon_str)) add(r) <- rast(df[c("lon", "lat", mon_str[i])])
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 279, 720, 480  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -56, 83.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source(s)   : memory
names       : 1971-02-01, 1971-03-01, 1971-04-01, 1971-05-01, 1971-06-01, 1971-07-01, ... 
min values  :    0.00000,     0.0000,     0.0000,     0.0000,     0.0000,      0.000, ... 
max values  :   96.28087,   150.5525,   491.3734,   448.1106,   269.3665,    331.089, ... 


Thanks for ncdfCF. It might be pointed out that months <- seq.Date(as.Date('1971-02-01'), as.Date('2011-01-01'), by  = 'month')  and r3 <- rast(df[c('lon', 'lat', as.character(months[3]))]) suggest that the onerous task of typing out dates could be put in a for, then cobbled together to layers 1:480, with c(, as rast employs it. The reason I saved this answer is it's clear approach to malformed netcdf, which seem plenty, but tactics thereafter few.

I have to echo Patrick's comment about "non-standard". I was able to get the data in withd_irr_h08.nc to plot using a Java app, but I had to hack the metadata a bit before the code I'm using was willing to recognize that the data were a collection of 64028 points using lon-lat coordinates.

@Chris Taken up your challenge in updated answer but used the names from the data.frame for that extra touch of automation.
